# Changes to libinput won't go into effect

Tags: libinput

I feel like I've done absolutely everything:

1) `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-libinput`

2) created `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/60-libinput.conf` and put the following:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Touchpad"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    Driver "libinput"
    option "Tapping" "true"
    option "NaturalScrolling" "false"
EndSection
```

3) Reboot

But no changes! Tap to click doesn't work, and natural scrolling is still on. What am I missing??? I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 on a xps 13 9360.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 30-libinput.conf for reference.

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad"
    Driver "libinput"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    Option "Tapping" "on"
    Option "DisableWhileTyping" "on"
    Option "TappingDrag" "off"
    Option "NaturalScrolling" "on"
        Option "TappingDragLock" "off"
EndSection
```

The only difference I can see is the order of options and the fact that you have capitalized the word Touchpad in the Identifier bit. It could be something as silly as that. I've had linux refuse to boot with a misconfigured libinput configuration file before I arrived at this one. :)

Note: I just looked at the system provided 40-libinput.conf and the identifiers are all lowercase, so that could be it.

Comment: Still no changes, unfortunately even after reboot and restart.